# Errors 850 and 812 when connecting to VPN on Windows Server 2012 machine

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, network-policy-server

I have a single Windows Server 2012 R2 (no active directory) machine that I want to configure to enable VPN.

I enabled the feature (just VPN) and configured a static IPv4 range (102.168.111.100-102.168.111.199), with the rest set to default.

- I connected from a Windows 8.1 client, and got an **850 error**.
- I adjusted the properties to use MS-CHAP v2, and got an **812 error**.

Since then I've tried:

- Turning the firewall off
- Overriding the "network policy authentication settings" to allow MS-CHAP v2
- Making any number of policy adjustments

So far, nothing has had any effect, and I'm welcome to any other ideas.

**Screenshot of tried configs, as requested:**

[image: screenshot in German]

Comment: Can you post up a screenshot of your client configuration screen for the authentication tab?

Comment: Under the heading for "encryption" (the second dropdown menu from the top) what is this set to (in English :) ) ? Also, have you enabled your users to be able to "dial-in" from their profiles/created a security group? Did you follow a tutorial (which one)?

Comment: This is the encryption tab; stuff like MS-CHAP v2 and EAP-MSCHAP v2 is not translated :)

Comment: Read my comment carefully... The second dropdown menu sets the encryption requirements (http://www.earthvpn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/win7-sstp.png - second red line). I can't understand what yours says. Try the "optional encryption" or "require encryption" entries in the menu...

Comment: When I do that, I get 0X800B0109, talking about a certificate

Comment: What exactly is `0X800B0109`?

Comment: Also, can you put in your question what VPN technology you're using (PPTP, SSTP, IPSEC etc.). Did you follow a tutorial to configure the VPN?